# OpenCV : SolvePnP is giving different results for same input parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv-solvepnp

I am trying to estimate the 3D Pose of an object using `solvePnP` in python.
But the problem is even if I kept both the camera and object static, the output of `solvePnP` (`rvec` and `tvec`) are changing. The world coordinates system is centered on the object and moves along with it. I am passing 4 image points and the corresponding 4 object points.

Calling SolvePnP:

```
retval, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(cam.object_points, cam.image_points, cam.camera_matrix, cam.dist_coefficients, None, None, False, cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
```

Output 1:

```
Image points: 
[[ 236.  243.]
 [  43.  368.]
 [ 404.  372.]
 [ 235.  357.]]
Object points: 
[[ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 6.5  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   6.5]
 [ 0.   6.5  0. ]]
R VECT==========
[[-0.56619693]
 [-2.27732794]
 [ 0.71053527]]
T VECT==========
[[ 0.54725923]
 [-0.45834745]
 [ 0.58522831]]
```

Output 2:

```
Image points: 
[[ 236.  243.]
 [  43.  369.]
 [ 404.  372.]
 [ 235.  357.]]
Object points: 
[[ 0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 6.5  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   6.5]
 [ 0.   6.5  0. ]]
R VECT==========
[[ 0.33325838]
 [ 2.12767845]
 [ 0.98248134]]
T VECT==========
[[ -2.60687131]
 [  0.37989386]
 [ 23.85078678]]
```

The object points and image points are identical but solvePnP still gives several different results. The above results are alternating one after another for alternative frames.

How should I resolve it?

Comment: `SolvePnP` is a [_non-deterministic_](https://faisalsikder.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/difference-between-algorithm-and-heuristic/) algorithm meaning that it is subject to chance, hence the different results with the same inputs.

Comment: But that drastic change I used ITERATIVE flag

Comment: is there a link that tells about non-determinism within solvePnp? I know there is a solvePnpRansac version, that is definitively non-deterministic.

Comment: Please provide all input data (camera matrix and distortion coefficients are missing in the example).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to look at [solvePnpGeneric](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga624af8a6641b9bdb487f63f694e8bb90) which returns all the possible solutions. solvePnp might be hesitating between two solutions and giving you alternating results.

[solvePnpGeneric](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga624af8a6641b9bdb487f63f694e8bb90) was introduced in [OpenCV 4.1.2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/33cb9c5ca54b99c934cafacc960548f6b9cc4060) and allows access to the different solutions as well as their re-projection error.